# MS Access: How to get value of textbox on button click?

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is a complete newbie question, but I couldn't find any solution online (at least nothing to my understanding). I want to make a form with a textbox and a button and on click, the button should take the value written in the textbox, find the row with that ID in a table and change an attribute to `unavailable`. Normally I would do this with a simple SQL statement:

```
UPDATE table SET available='NO' WHERE id = *textbox.value*;
```

What should I write instead of textbox.value so that it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to an open form:

```
UPDATE table SET available='NO' WHERE id = Forms!MyForm!MyTextbox
```

Assuming that the form is the main form and not a subform. You can also run SQL in VBA. Make sure you do not update a record via a form and via a query or code at the same time.

Re Comments

In this case, the problem is corruption, something I often forget to watch out for. You will find a good article here : http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/corruptmdbs.htm, including Decompile.

Comment: Whenever I run the query it opens a dialog box asking for the value of Forms!Gestiune!idInchiriere. Since there are no typos, what could be the problem?
I have programming experience, but nothing in Visual Basic, I've looked on some code, but I'm stumped...

Comment: If you are using MS Access 2010, you can use intellisense in the query design window to get the name that Access has on the form and control, otherwise, you can use the Expression wizard. If you are completely convinced that there is no problem with the names, can you run a message box from the open form that refers to Forms!Gestiune!idInchiriere to test?

Comment: Also, to reiterate what Remou said, double check that your form is open when you run the query. It sounds like it may not be open, or you spelled the control incorrectly.

Comment: The form is open, I'm writing in the textbox and pressing the button in the form when it pops up the dialog box. I tried the auto fill out thing, clicked on the right things and it still doesn't work, so maybe I'm doing something else wrong.

Comment: Have you exited the textbox so that it is populated? What do you get if you type `?Forms!Gestiune!idInchiriere` in the immediate window or run `MsgBox Forms!Gestiune!idInchiriere` & " xxxxx" through code?

Comment: Excuse my noobness... type that where? :)

Comment: Type ctrl+G to open the immediate window. It is a sort of chalk board, then just paste `?Forms!Gestiune!idInchiriere` and hit return.

Comment: I get Runtime Error lots of numbers. I'm clearly not doing it right.

Comment: I have added a note on a message box, put the code in an ordinary module and run it. If you do not know how, do you know how to upload to dropbox?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22202/discussion-between-floiancu-and-remou)

Answer (score 1):

Getting the value from the text box is even easier if:

- the query is executed from VBA
- the VBA is in the same form as the text box

If I understood the question right, this is the case here.

Then you can just do this:

```vb
Dim SQL As String

'case 1: when the id is a string value
SQL = "UPDATE table SET available='NO' WHERE id = '" & Me.NameOfTheTextBox & "';"

'case 2: when the id is a numeric value
SQL = "UPDATE table SET available='NO' WHERE id = " & Me.NameOfTheTextBox & ";"

CurrentDB.Execute SQL
```